# Python theano undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm error

Tags: python, theano, keras, archlinux

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)

def f(x):    
    return 2 * x + 5

f = np.vectorize(f)
y = f(x)    

def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
    return model

model = baseline_model()
model.fit(x, y, nb_epoch=100, verbose = 0)
```

But on last line it throws this error: `ImportError: /home/puck/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--MANJARO-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5--3.6.0-64/tmpgk36rmkt/mf0c860ada3decf909d2c7248bdfcff39.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/hdQKT3d6) is full traceback.
This is my first experience with keras and theano, so I have no idea what to do.

Some info about software versions:

```
Linux 4.4.52-1-MANJARO
GCC 6.3.1
Anaconda 4.3.0
Python 3.6.0 
IPython 5.1.0
Theano 0.8.2
Keras 1.2.2
```

Comment: I found [same issue](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5141), but suggested there solution doesn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix problem I installed gcc 4.9.3 and added in `~/.theanorc` these lines:

```
[global]
cxx = /usr/bin/g++-4.9.3
```

Comment: I have give you same suggestion to reduce your gcc/g++ version to 4.9.

Comment: @AvkashChauhan, I didn’t downgrade my gcc, I installed 4.9 without removing last version of gcc

Answer (score 1):

As you have installed pre-built theano package in your machine it is expecting certain gcc and dependent libs to be in the machine to make the call. The solution provided in the github link is still valid for you however because you are not building the code, that solution will not work for you because theano is still accessing the preinstalled libs.

Here is what you can try:

- You must have gcc and g++ higher version which are not compatible to theano so remove the gcc and g++ by uninstalling them using OS commands
- Remove theano package
- Install gcc and g++ to 4.9 version as this is most command version
- Reinstall theano > $ pip3 install theano --user

I believe this help you to get your theano working.

Comment: I have many packages what depends on gcc, so I cannot remove it. Is there way to have 2 versions of gcc and choose in theano what version it should use?

Comment: Also now I have installed both versions: http://pastebin.com/raw/w0yq2a8r

Comment: When you build a package you can pass links to alternative location to gcc/g++ and it will work. For the prebuild package you would need to customize the environment to pass proper libs. What u can do is create bunch of exports in a command window to pass gcc/g++ 4.9 and once make sure it work, try it.. very hard problem to solve with prebuilt package but can try.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the version of gcc, but there is a simpler solution

Comment: I strongly advise against uninstalling your current version of  gcc/g++; there is no problem installing old versions alongside new versions, and you may break other dependencies. See @KgOfHedgehogs 's answer for how to point to a specific version you have installed.