# undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm

Tags: python, c++, caffe

I am using [apollocaffe](https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe) and [Reinspect](https://github.com/Russell91/ReInspect). `Apollocaffe` is in c++ library and `Reinspect` is in python that uses `apollocaffe library`. 
I build apollocaffe using g++-4.8.5.
When I run the command `python -m pdb train.py config-- config.json`, I have this error,

```
ImportError: '/home/xxx/Softwares/Libraries/apollocaffe_22_3_17/build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm'
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5141) (theano) thread, looks like you're using incompatible gcc versions. Try to move to another gcc version. (See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729958/python-theano-undefined-symbol-zdlpvm-error))

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be Cuda was built with one g++ version and Apollocaffe was built with another g++ version. Now I rebuild all with same g++ version and now it works well.