# Failing to install R igraph - undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm

Tags: r, centos, igraph

I am failing to install igraph for R 3.3.3 via `install.packages`("igraph").

My R session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
```

If I try to install igraph:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/R-3.3.3/R_3.3.3/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
/usr/local/R-3.3.3/R_3.3.3/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I have reinstalled R which did not solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172985/undefined-symbol-zdlpvm) I would speculate that you have an issue with incompatible `gcc` versions.

Please double-check, but based on [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=CentOS) it seems that CentOS 6.9 ships with a fairly old `gcc 4.4.7` version. Is there a possibility for you to install and use a more recent `gcc` version? I've got an old Linux machine that has `gcc 4.9.3` on which I successfully installed `igraph`.

By the way, GCC 7 (`gcc 7.2.0`) is the most current release.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. You are correct usually CentOS runs with 4.4.7 but I already had that upgraded before. My gcc that I used here is version 6.3.1. Could that still incompatible?

Comment: @OOMana There's been one issue reported [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5141), where a similar error was potentially related to a `gcc 6.x` version. It might be worth a shot to install `gcc 4.9` and see if `igraph` installs correctly. Sorry for not being able to give more specific help. I've successfully installed `igraph` on various Mac OS versions, but it's a different story with Mac's `clang/LLVM` compiler altogether. The error definitely seems to be `gcc` related.

Comment: You guys were absolutley right. It works now with gcc 4.9. Thanks again